# Could These Reptungulates Run?

Tags: anatomy, reptiles

The reptungulates are a group of animals that are a combination of ungulates and herptiles.  Externally, they resemble ungulates, but their limb have a reptilian anatomy with the shoulder and hip joints being on the chest/belly. The shoulder blades and pelves are very muscular and highly mobile, to power the limbs

They are around the size of deer and equines

[image: Differences in the Joints]

Could this unique anatomy work for a fast cursorial animal like regular ungulates?

Comment: How large are they? I ask because lizards are actually pretty quick animals. Try catching one. They won't be so nimble if they had ungulate limbs.

Comment: Last time I checked every reptile has an ankle joint. Is that an oversight on your part?

Comment: @sphennings They do have ankles, but they aren't part of the leg structure and only allow the foot itself to move

Comment: Your diagram goes shoulder to foot somewhere in there a reptile has an ankle.

Comment: See remark in the Hugag topic, I think you'll want ankles to run.. at least humans do need ankles to land their feet properly, on each step, while running. The forces are considerable. When the foot is very sturdy, broad and strong, you may get around it. When you have flexible and strong toes, that may solve the issue. But the more *irregular* your ground is, e.g. in forests, the nastier the landing issue will become.

Comment: I'm sorry we need much more information before answering this question. Please narrow the question (run how fast, where?) and explain the problem that makes you think it may not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question is asking very specifically to compare the limb design of the reptungulate to a regular ungulate animal. Both [even-number toed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_even-toed_ungulates_by_population) and [odd-number toed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_odd-toed_ungulates_by_population) ungulates are quite fast by their design, because they have the three joints you point out, can limit the range of motion of those joints to reduce wear and stress, and can avoid long and vulnerable bone lengths. The unfortunate consequence of their design is that a broken limb is normally fatal as it cannot recover.

Your design will not be able to run and maneuver like an ungulate for several reasons.

- The limb length is shorter without a shoulder, and where the shoulder should be, there is rigid bones that will have no "give" to absorb running stress.
- The second reason is there are only two joints to carry the stride, so the stride must be shorter unless the joints bend at a much steeper angle than an ungulate limb of the same length.
- It will be taking all the force of its footfall on limbs steeply bent, which will destroy any known ligamentatios tissue.

This creature will have a very awkward gait, and must travel carefully to avoid tearing ligaments or fracturing bones. There will be no reptungulate gazelles, or horses, and probably no rhinoceroses or even tapirs who can keep up with their warm-blooded analogues.

Find a slow and sedentary lifestyle for these creatures. Even a cow coud outrun the reptungulate counterpart, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

Why not? Plantigrade motion might not be the most efficient running method, but it's used by humans, bears, and was used by all mammals before the evolution of digitigrade and unguligrade locomotion. And anyone who believes a bear can't run is in for a rude surprise.